# Java - Encog 3.2 - RPROP network not updating weights

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

I researched a lot of questions and examples but I can't seem to find out what's wrong with my RPROP NN. It's also the first time I use Encog so I'm wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to train the network to recognize a cat by feeding it images (50x50), then converting it to grayscale and feeding the network an input double[][] along with a target double[][]. I noticed that the error is constantly at 4.0, so I performed a dumpWeights() with every training iteration to see what's going on. I noticed that the weights were constantly zero. I then went back to the basics to see if I'm doing things right so I modified it for an XOR problem:

```
//////////First created the network:

BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();

network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 2));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationBiPolar(), true, 2));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationBiPolar(), false, 1));

network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
network.reset(); 

//////Then created my data set and target vector (ideal vector) and fed it to a new RPROP training class:

final double targetVector[][] = { { -1 }, { 1.0 }, { 1.0 }, { -1 } };
final double inputData[][] = { { -1, -1 }, { 1.0, -1 },{ -1, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 } };

MLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(inputData, targetVector);

final ResilientPropagation train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

///////train network

int epoch = 1;

    do{
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error : " + train.getError()) ;
        epoch++;

        System.out.println(network.dumpWeights());

    }while(train.getError() > 0.01) ;
        train.finishTraining();

        System.out.println("End of training");
```

I get the following output, notice the lines of 0.0 as a result of the network.dumpWeights() method:

Epoch #132636 Error : 2.0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Epoch #132637 Error : 2.0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Epoch #132638 Error : 2.0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Epoch #132639 Error : 2.0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Epoch #132640 Error : 2.0

... and so on.

Anything obvious you can see that I'm doing wrong here? I also tried a 2-3-1 architecture as the XORHelloWorld.java example implemented.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried changing the data set and targets replacing -1 with 0.0 and changing the activation function to ActivationSigmoid and it seems to work fine. Output after the changes:

Epoch #48 Error : 0.007620154423525455
7.960025653965789,-14.182680838427633,-1.2611584281744572,-1.2781030810307181,10.50534716500236,9.690907558129927,-6.933186134247863,1.3562102936861975,1.6115414799461512,-2.8203649806273847,6.8557107101634545,-4.423294726521557,2.52133147494805
End of training

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your hidden layer to a TANH activation function, such as this:

```
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 2));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 2));
network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationBiPolar(), false, 1));
```

With this change, I can get your example above to converge. I think it will work better than Sigmoid, if you are using -1 to 1 as the input.  It is okay to is a linear activation function (i.e. ActivationBiPolar as the output activation function) but you need something such as sigmoid/tanh as the hidden.  Something that does not just return 1.0 as the derivative, like the linear functions do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeff. I tried your suggestion and I can see a slight change but essentially I have the same outcome. The weights were updated only once and the error is 2.0:

0,0,0,0.4884507325564466,0.17375282591824576,-0.9245120358699924,0.39254840143179537,0.5835401350814016,0.9597289079109588

Epoch #2207520 Error : 2.0

The only way I was able to get this to converge is by using the ActivationSigmoid with values of 1's and 0's as the input and target values, or using an ActivationSigmoid with 1's and -1's as the input and target vector with values 1's and 0's

Comment: I also tried with the ActivationBipolarSteepenedSigmoid and the network converges only sometimes. On one try I got:

Epoch #45 Error : 0.008887634646260537

On the other try I got:

Epoch #179852 Error : 0.999049357917208 (and kept on running)